# Entity bean 3.0 composite key issue

Tags: jpa

1: I have a table as shown below :

Name                                      Null?    Type

---

ATX_ID                                    NOT NULL NUMBER(16)
 ATX_GLM_CD                                NOT NULL NUMBER(5)
 ATX_CRDR_FLG                              NOT NULL VARCHAR2(1)
 ATX_AMT                                   NOT NULL NUMBER(15,2)
 ATX_STTS                                  NOT NULL VARCHAR2(1)
 ATX_TCM_ID                                NOT NULL NUMBER(16)
 ATX_TXN_DT                                NOT NULL DATE
 ATX_CRTE_BY                               NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)
 ATX_CRTE_DT                               NOT NULL DATE

The columns ATX_ID,ATX_GLM_CD and ATX_CRDR_FLG form a composite primary key.

2: I have created an entity bean class for the above table as follows :

@Entity
public class AcctngTxns implements Serializable {

```
private BigDecimal atxAmt;
private String atxStts;
private BigDecimal atxTcmId;
private Date atxTxnDt;
private String atxCrteBy;
private Date atxCrteDt;
```

@EmbeddedId
    private AcctngTxnsPK acctngTxnsPK;

```
public AcctngTxns() {
    //super();
}

/*getters and setters*/
```

}

@Embeddable
public class AcctngTxnsPK implements Serializable {

```
private long atxId;
private long atxGlmCd;
private String atxCrdrFlg;

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public AcctngTxnsPK() {
    //super();
}

/*necessary overrides*/
```

}

3: /*orm.xml*/

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">

4: /*persistence.xml*/

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
    
        DataSource
        
        com.nseit.ncfm2.data.ejb.entity.AcctngTxns

5: While accessing the entity bean via a session bean,I am getting the following exception :

<[weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext@1a1bc8f - appName: '_auto_generated_ear_', name: 'AWebApp', context-path: '/AWebApp', spec-version: '2.5'] Servlet failed with Exception
javax.ejb.EJBException: EJB Exception: ; nested exception is: 
     org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Fields "com.nseit.ncfm2.data.ejb.entity.AcctngTxns.acctngTxnsPK" are not a default persistent type, and do not have any annotations indicating their persistence strategy.  If you do not want these fields to be persisted, annotate them with @Transient.
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.java:105)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.invoke(RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.java:87)
    at $Proxy127.gottaAccessEntity3(Unknown Source)
    at jsp_servlet.__result.*jspService(*_result.java:115)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
 org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Fields "com.nseit.ncfm2.data.ejb.entity.AcctngTxns.acctngTxnsPK" are not a default persistent type, and do not have any annotations indicating their persistence strategy.  If you do not want these fields to be persisted, annotate them with @Transient.
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceMetaDataFactory.validateStrategies(PersistenceMetaDataFactory.java:399)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceMetaDataFactory.load(PersistenceMetaDataFactory.java:205)
    at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.getMetaDataInternal(MetaDataRepository.java:474)
    at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.getMetaData(MetaDataRepository.java:294)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.newObjectId(BrokerImpl.java:1114)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

> 

7: Certainly,I do not want the primary key fields to be updated.

8: I tried to figure out the implementation of the below points mentioned in JPA documentation :

## A composite primary key must be represented and mapped to multiple fields or properties of the entity class, or must be represented and mapped as an embeddable class.

## If the class is mapped to multiple fields or properties of the entity class, the names and types of the primary key fields or properties in the primary key class must match those of the entity class.

8: Please help me in resolving the issue.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution by trial-and-error method. It seems that with JPA 1.0,it is necessary to mention the embedded-id in orm.xml file as follows :

Thanks.

Comment: <embedded-id name="acctngTxnsPK">
 <attribute-override name="atxId">
  <column name="ATX_ID" table="ACCTNG_TXNS" />
 </attribute-override>
 <attribute-override name="atxGlmCd">
  <column name="ATX_GLM_CD" table="ACCTNG_TXNS"></column>
 </attribute-override>
 <attribute-override name="atxCrdrFlg">
  <column name="ATX_CRDR_FLG" table="ACCTNG_TXNS" />
 </attribute-override>
</embedded-id>